# jQuery Mobile 1.4.x: How can I put a popup after 5 seconds the app starts

Tags: jquery-mobile, jquery-mobile-popup

I can't do a click event it's suppose that the popup starts after 5 seconds after the app runs.

Any ideas?

UPDATE:

Here is the iFrame Popup example. I just changed the src from where the ads are going to come from.

The isue is that I need to set a timeout after 5 seconds to use the popup, but I'm a little confused on how will the timeout function will render the popup because I can't use a click event.

```
<a href="#popupMap" data-rel="popup" data-position-to="window" class="ui-btn ui-corner-all ui-shadow ui-btn-inline">Open Map</a>
<div data-role="popup" id="popupMap" data-overlay-theme="a" data-theme="a" data-corners="false" data-tolerance="15,15">
    <a href="#" data-rel="back" class="ui-btn ui-btn-b ui-corner-all ui-shadow ui-btn-a ui-icon-delete ui-btn-icon-notext ui-btn-right">Close</a>
    <iframe src="http://googleadmobORadsense.com" width="480" height="320" seamless=""></iframe>
</div>
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/window.setTimeout

Comment: I have being more explicit with the issue. I know I have to use a timeout function but the problem is how to render the popup after those 5 seconds.

Comment: http://api.jquerymobile.com/popup/#method-open - $("#popupMap").popup( "open");

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$(document).on("mobileinit", function () {
  setTimeout(function () {
    //show your popup here
  }, 5000);
});
```

Comment: When answering a question it is generally a good idea to provide enough explanation to go along with the code so that folks will understand why they should use each part of the sample code and what each part will do.